# Make HttPRequest From Blazor WASM Client

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blazor

I want to make request from my Blazor app but only from Client side via HttpClient.The problem is with cors.Why this is not problem from server side.I make all like from documentation.Here is the requets and error.Also I tried to add all possible headers for this solution.

```
client.BaseAddress =new Uri(@"https://login.microsoftonline.com");
        
        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "074c9330-dc89786455334435f532"));
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "NQDTMNmj-3iyuttre4323234e5r~dF"));
        keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://someapi.onmicrosoft.com/api/.default"));

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/someapi.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token");
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

        return await client.SendAsync(request);
```

And thre error is:

> from origin 'http://localhost:8090' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field middleware-ctor is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Ok but I try this with tree diferent cloud APi's how it is possible.

Comment: Google "CORS" .

Comment: The server will have to set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for your browser to make CORS requests. There isn't anything you can add to your request to fix it, that would make CORS pointless.

Comment: This comes from Microsoft. If it is an external Rest API you can't do anything.